# How to get direct link to video using Youtube API v3?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

How can I get direct link to video using Youtube API v3?

This link:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=7lCDEYXw3mM&key=AIzaSyDXh6R0ZFXXXeX09Pp2y22uH3fJkdGwpyQ&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status,recordingDetails,player

not return any full link to download video ex via cURL.

Please, Help me :)

Answer (score 0):

You already have the id, so just prepend `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=`

Comment: And how download video using this link? It's impossible.
I need full direct link

Comment: Ah, now I understand. You want to bypass the Terms of Service and download the MP4 source file. Of course they don't provide this in the API because they don't want you to do it.